# Full width footer menu with drop up menu equal scaling

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, footer

Hello i need this to work fast, but i really stuck right now!

I have a full width footer menu with the list items centered and with a equal scaling on browser size and i think i have it working correctly now, but i can't to seem to get the drop-up menu to work on hover in the same way with the list items on top of each other (vertical list menu) and in the equal scaling like the footer menu.

Please can some one help me with this, it must be quite easy.

Thank you!!

```
<footer>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">Share</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" id="scroll-top">Top</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="funcShow(event);">Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/L7noytpf/1/

Answer (score 0):

can u please use the below CSS

for more clarity see the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L7noytpf/3)**

CSS:

```
   footer ul ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}


footer ul ul {
    bottom: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 273px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i meant not horizontal, but vertical list menu above the share button with the same width. Do you know how?

Comment: thanks! is it possible that the width of the drop u menu has the same width as the menu items on browser size. Maybe 33.333% trick? Or is there a beter way? Thank you again Jai!

Comment: Can you show me how you will do it? 33.333% seems not that waterproof with scaling.